# Error: Django model form data not being saved in the database

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I'm trying to create a blog model but the form data is not being saved in the database after submitting the form.
**views.py**

```
def postsform(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BlogForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog')
        else:
            form = BlogForm()
            messages.warning(request, "Opps! Something went wrong.")
            return render(request, 'blog/postform.html', {'form':form})
    else:
        form = BlogForm()
        return render(request, 'blog/postform.html', {'form':form})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django_summernote.widgets import SummernoteWidget

class BlogForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        widgets = {
            'blog': SummernoteWidget(),
        }
        fields = ['title', 'featureImg', 'blog', 'meta_description', 'keyword', 'author']
```

**models.py**

```
class BlogPost(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=999)
    featureImg = ProcessedImageField(upload_to = 'blog/', format='JPEG',options={'quality':60}, null=True)
    slug = models.CharField(max_length=999, blank=True,null= True)
    blog = models.TextField()
    meta_description = models.TextField()
    keyword = models.TextField()
    author = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_on = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_on = models.DateField(auto_now=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if BlogPost.objects.filter(title=self.title).exists():
            extra = str(randint(1, 1000000))
            self.slug = slugify(self.title) + "-" + extra
        else:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super(BlogPost, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

**html**

```
<form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit">Publish</button>
    </form>
```

I've tried finding where I made the mistake but couldn't find it. After submitting the form the warning message pops up and the form doesn't get submitted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *not* construct a new form, since then it will not render the errors. Likely you did not pass `request.FILES`, and the [**`enctype="…"`** <sup>[mdn-doc]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) is also missing in the `<form>` tag:

```
def postsform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BlogForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blog')
        else:
            # no new BlogForm
            messages.warning(request, 'Oops! Something went wrong.')
    else:
        form = BlogForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/postform.html', {'form': form})
```

and in the HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.as_p}}
    <button type="submit">Publish</button>
</form>
```